# Rotate X,Y Coordinates from Bottom Right to Top left

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm using NodeXL to plot a lot of points which are actual coordinates for cities.

The thing is that the way it's plotted now is that North America is on the Bottom Right but it should be on the top left like on a normal map.

It's like this for all of the points so pretty much I need to rotate the whole graph so that what's on the bottom right will be top left after transformation, and what's on the top right will be on the bottom left.

I have two columns with X and Y points as follows (for example):

```
X       Y
6,238.2 9,896.0
6,141.9 9,896.0
```

I'm  not sure the formula or Math behind this kind of rotation.

**The graph is only positive** so from (0,0) upward and outward to the right, there are no negative values on the x or y axis.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Instead of plotting x and y plot (width-x) and (height-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer:

To quote @Tim Williams: `Instead of plotting x and y plot (width-x) and (height-y)`

Example:

[image: SO13889501 example]